# More efficient way to deal with KeyError from dictionary

Tags: python

I want to find the country names for a data frame columns with top level domains such as 'de', 'it', 'us'.. by using the iso3166 package.
There are domains in the dataset that does not exist in iso3166, therefore, Value Error got raised.
I tried to solve the value error by letting the code return Boolean values but it runs for a really long time. Will be great to know how to speed it up.

Sample data: df['country']

```
0    an
1    de
2    it
```

My code (Note the code does not raise KeyError error. My question is how to make it faster)

```py
df['country_name'] = df['country'].apply(lambda x: countries.get(x)[0] if \ 
    df['country'].str.find(x).any() == countries.get(x)[1].lower() else 'unknown')
```

`df['country]` is the data frame column. `countries.get()` is for getting country names from iso3166

`df['country'].str.find(x).any()` finds top level domains  and `countries.get(x)[1].lower()`returns top level domains. If they are the same then I use `countries.get(x)[0]` to return the country name

Expected output

```
country country_name
an      unknown
de      Germany
it      Italy
```

Error if I run `df['country_name'] = df['country'].apply(lambda x: countries.get(x)[0])` (I renamed the dataframe so it's different from the error message)

````
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-110-d51176ce2978> in <module>
----> 1 bf['country_name'] = bf['country'].apply(lambda x: countries.get(x)[0])

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)
   3846             else:
   3847                 values = self.astype(object).values
-> 3848                 mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
   3849 
   3850         if len(mapped) and isinstance(mapped[0], Series):

pandas/_libs/lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

<ipython-input-110-d51176ce2978> in <lambda>(x)
----> 1 bf['country_name'] = bf['country'].apply(lambda x: countries.get(x)[0])

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/iso3166/__init__.py in get(self, key, default)
    358 
    359         if r == NOT_FOUND:
--> 360             raise KeyError(key)
    361 
    362         return r

KeyError: 'an'```
````

Comment: Can you add the full `Traceback` message and a sample of what your `DataFrame` looks like (perhaps show the output of `df.head()`? Also, the name of your `DataFrame` appears to change in this code. It's not clear if this is a typo.

Comment: Use `defaultdict` https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict

Comment: The question title does not match its content, can you please provide sample input and output? Some small full code snippet maybe?

Comment: Looks like the problem must be in your `countries.get()` function. Can you provide the code for that as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little error handling and defining your logic outside of the `apply()` method should get you where you want to go. Something like:

```py
def get_country_name(x):
    try:
        return countries.get(x)[0]
    except:
        return 'unknown'
    
df['country_name'] = df['country'].apply(lambda x: get_country_name(x))
```

Comment: thanks! I did try 'try .. except' but it throw me another error.

Comment: Post that as another question! We can do this all night.

Answer (score 0):

This James Tollefson's answer, narrowed down to its core, didn't want to change his answer too much, here's the implementation:

```py
def get_country_name(x: str) -> str:
    return countries[x][0] if countries.get(x) else 'unknown'
    
df['country_name'] = df['country'].apply(get_country_name)
```